# Static members of classes used by Azure functions

Tags: azure-functions

I know that if you declare a static member in the same class where you define your Run method, it shares that between multiple invocations of your Azure function.

But say I use a helper class called MyFunctionHelper and use it in my function. If I declare static members in that class, are they also shared between function invocations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It's still the same process / app domain, and all .NET static classes/methods are shared within this boundary. There is no difference whether it's in the same class or another class.